# Loading errors with jQuery pickadate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use pickadate.js for a text input but I cannot get it to work on my server. I made a fiddle and it works fine, but when I copy that code over (I even put everything in the HTML box of the Fiddle so the code is 100% the same), I get the following errors

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier picker.js:487
Uncaught ReferenceError: Picker is not defined picker.date.js:23
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pickadate'
```

Here is the code. There is absolutely no other code on the page than this.

```
<input type = "textbox" id="pickadate_input"></input>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src = "http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/lib/picker.js"></script>


<script src = "http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/lib/picker.date.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#pickadate_input').pickadate()
</script>
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgUZa/) with the same code. Notice that there are no scripts included on the left. What would cause the different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 487 in picker.js has a weird chracter in it:

```
options = thingIsObject && $.isPlainObject( value ) ?Â value : options || {}
```

after the "?", take this out and it should work.

Comment: That's the official hosting from pickadate.js. Regardless, it works on the fiddle but not my site.

Comment: I downloaded it and hosted locally. Still getting the same errors. I opened the file and that Â character is not there, however it does appear in the errors which is strange. Somehow it's being inserted at runtime

Comment: It's not being added at runtime, I think maybe you just have a file encoding when you edit it which makes it not show up. Try utf-8 when viewing the file. I deleted then re-added the line by hand and it works locally for me.

Comment: thanks, I did the same thing and it worked. I've never encountered this issue before, is it common?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hosting the files locally?

Is your site running `https`? If so, your site may not be loading insecure content since the picker resources start with `http`.

If you use Google Chrome, you can look at the Network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools to see if those JavaScript files are loading successfully.

Comment: No, my site is not using https. I did look, all files are loading correctly.

Comment: I hosted locally and still get the errors. I opened the file and that character is not there. It is somehow being inserted at runtime.